# Why won't this ng-pattern filter numbers?

Tags: angularjs, regex

I have an AngularJS single page application.  One view has a textbox that I want to only accept numbers for an integer field.  I have entered this code in the controller and this textbox in the view, but when I run the view it accepts any keyboard characters.  Can you tell me how I need to modify this to work?

```js
    $scope.FilterNumbersOnly = /^\d+$/;

                <input ng-model="x.COLUMN_VALUE" ng-pattern="FilterNumbersOnly" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [AngularJS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern), `ng-pattern` will set the `pattern` key on the `error` object when the values input into the text-based field do not pass the specified regex test.

This says nothing about prohibiting users from inputting text. If you would like to add that behavior, you need to listen to the `pattern` key on the `error` object and attach handlers to it. When the input is invalid, the error object will reflect this, and you should respond by preventing user input. Or you can take whatever such action you deem necessary.

To prevent user input, you can set the `disabled` attribute on the input field when the `pattern` key on the `error` object is set.

One simple way to accomplish this is with the `ng-if` directive.

```
<input disabled ng-if="!form.input.$valid" />
<input ng-if="form.input.$valid" />
```

Here is a [link to a working example](http:////plnkr.co/edit/RwdL68s961ehQ3xrUpn6?p=preview).

Comment: wcarroll, thanks.  I may try that.  It looks like it may be simpler just to handle a keypress or keyup event in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using:

1. [ngChange](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) *directive*;
2. [ngMask](https://github.com/candreoliveira/ngMask) *module* (Always I need handle inputs with masks I use it).

I made this snippet showing both ways:

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";
  angular.module('app', ['ngMask'])
    .controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.checkNumber = function() {
        $scope.input = $scope.input.replace(/\D+/, '');
      }
    })
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ngMask/3.1.1/ngMask.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <form name="form" novalidate>
    <label for="withoutMask">Input without mask: </label>
    <input type="text" id="withoutMask" ng-model="input" ng-change="checkNumber()">
    <hr>
    <label for="mask">Input with mask: </label>
    <input type="text" id="mask" mask="d" repeat="15" restrict="reject" limit="false" ng-model="otherInput">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

why not use the built-in HTML support?

```
<input type="number">
```

supported - http://caniuse.com/#search=input%20type%3D%22number%22

Comment: I tried changing the input textbox to this <input type="number" ng-model="x.COLUMN_VALUE" /> and it still allows non-numeric keys to be entered in the textbox.

Comment: the only letter value that should be allowed is "e" for scientific notation.  ex - http://codepen.io/jusopi/pen/NAvyLK.  If that doesn't suit your needs, you could always write a directive that listens to the input and then disallows certain characters based on a particular pattern.  This could operate prior to any submission/blur validation.